# What age were these Britons in A.D. 43?

Tags: roman-empire, britain, iron-age, celts

I have been doing a lot of research on the Roman invasion of Britain and have come across a number of problems with information.

My question is how old specific people were in 43 AD. I have approximated the age of some but others elude me:

- Cunobelinos: 62
- Epaticcos: 57 (died in ~A.D.35 age 49)
- Adminios: 37
- Togodumnos: 34
- Caratacos: 33
- Boudica:
- Prasutagos:
- Cartimandua:
- Verica:

Comment: Do note that the information simply isn't there for a lot of cases, unfortunately.

Comment: Take note, there wasn't year 0, so everybody will appear to be 1 year younger than logical if they pass the age of 43 of course in case if exact data available.

Comment: I too think you will have great difficulty finding even approximate ages for these persons. As to the BC/AD problem, the usual practice in technical astronomical literature is to call 1 BC the year “0” and 2 BC the year “-1” etc. If you follow this you will be less likely to make a mistake when calculating ages. So, if someone is born in 13 BC = -12, then his age in AD 43 will be 43 –(-12) = 43 + 12 = 55.

Comment: You might estimate the age of Boudicca and Cartimandua by seeing what age their children are, if any, and guessing that the first children were born near the age 18-20.  This would estimate Boudicca to be late 20s-mid 30s.

Comment: Alright! Thanks anyway, Iv found sources elsewhere stating Boudica was around the age of 30. I'll carry on researching and let you know if I find anything. Also I have read that Verica was "Elderly" during the time of the invasion but what age this is exactly I don't know, I would assume around 60. Ill look into his ancestors an try figure it out. I believe his father is Commios of Gaul.

Answer (score 6):

*This is a **community wiki**. Feel free to add and / or improve on this answer.*

As Semaphore noted in his comment, "the information simply isn't there for a lot of cases" but here are some estimates or 'best guesses' based on what little I have been able to find.

**Ages in 43 AD**

- [Boudica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudica) was at least in her late teens in 43 AD but Oldcat's estimate of late 20s to mid 30s seems likely. Before she rebelled in 60/61 AD, her daughters were raped; unless the Romans raped young children, the children must have been not less than about 14 or 15 years old at that time. If this assumption is correct, and we assume Boudica's eldest was born when she was around 18, the Queen must have been at least 32 years old in 60 AD. [geni.com](https://www.geni.com/people/Boudicca-queen-of-the-Iceni/6000000003827309569), though, gives her date of birth as circa. 30 AD (no source for this), making her only about 13 in 43 AD - this seems unlikely though.
- [Prasutagos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasutagus), Boudica's husband, was probably at least 43 years old in 43 AD. Wikipedia, citing Tacitus, says he "lived a long and prosperous life" so he was probably at least 60 years old when he died around 60 AD. [geni.com](https://www.geni.com/people/Prasutagus-king-of-the-Iceni/6000000002118940751) gives his date of birth as circa. 10 AD (again, no source), making him about 33 years old in 43 AD.
- [Cartimandua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartimandua) reigned from about 43 AD. It seems unlikely that a child would have had enough influence to have been able to form "a large tribal agglomeration that became loyal to Rome" so she must have been at least 20 in 43 AD. [geni.com](https://www.geni.com/people/Cartismandua-Queen-of-the-Brigantes/6000000011782162644) (again unsourced) says she was born circa. 10 AD, making her 33 years old in 43 AD - this seems reasonable given that she "[appears to have been widely influential in early Roman Britain.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartimandua)"
- [Verica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verica) became King in about 15 AD, succeeding his elder brother [Eppillus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eppillus) who seems to have become King as early as 20 BC. If Eppilus ruled for around 35 years, his younger brother Verica must have been an old man in 43 AD, even if there was a huge age difference between the two. Verica, who was on friendly terms with Rome, was ousted as king sometime after 40 BC. As there is no evidence that the Romans reinstated him after the invasion, Verica may well have died by 43 AD.

Comment: Boudica's daughters are thought to have been around 12 years old. There is a statue of her in London somewhere which shows her and two young looking girls of around this age.

Comment: The age of marriage for females in Rome was 12, 14 for males which would make the daughters legal in Roman eyes. Her daughters would have been born around 49 AD.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have a source for "Boudica's daughters are thought to have been around 12 years old" (other than a 19th century statue)? If so, please feel free to edit this community wiki (or leave the info in a comment so that I can insert).

Comment: I took that from a university site (unc.edu) but I can't find where that "fact" came from. I suspect it was an assumption made by historians within the last couple of centuries but based on what I can't say.

Comment: They were likely unmarried so can't be too old. The only other thing I could find was the execution of Junilla, Sejanus's daughter. He was a powerful senator in Rome who was executed for treason along with his family. His daughter, who was about 15 was a virgin. There was some issue about executing a virgin so she was raped first with the noose around her neck. Presumably she was hung immediately after.